# Definir múltiplos path iniciais para pacotes diferentes no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet

Eu utilizo:

- spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Surgiu a necessidade de eu utilizar dois path diferentes nas minhas classes anotadas com @RestController @RequestMapping, hoje o meu application.propeties esta da seguinte forma:

```
server.port=8080
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api-a/v1
```

Porem com essa necessidade tbm vou precisar usar o path: /api-b/v1 em outras classes

Eu consigo definir um path inicial para cada pacote? ou existe alguma maneira mais correta de fazer este tipo de tratativa?

Não consegui achar nada no google que me ajudasse, achei algo sobre desacoplar o projeto e definir diferentes modulos com application.properties para cada modulo, mas não era o caso do exemplo que eu achei, como não tive muito sucesso na minha busca gostaria de saber se alguem poderia me ajudar.

Comment: A pessoa deu um deslike na minha duvida e nem pra comenta o que eu fiz de errado para corrigir minha duvida '-'

Comment: Por que você não deixa o contexto padrão ("/") e coloca o path `api-a, api-b, api-x` dentro da anotação @RequestMapping, exemplo: `@RequestMapping("/api-a/v1)` ?

Comment: atualmente eu utilizo desta forma, porem se eu precisar trocar o `api-a` para outro nome eu teria que alterar em todas as minhas classes controllers(deixando assim suscetível a erros), minha aplicação depende de dois path's padrão que foram configurados em dois gateways diferentes, este é o motivo de eu ter que usar `api-a` e o `api-b`.